# How to configure Hibernate AnnotatedClasses in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am currently moving an old Spring project to Spring boot. In the old project we were initialising datasource and session factory in xml context explicitly. But after moving to Spring Boot, all is happening implicitly through Spring boot and application.properties.

My question is that, with no explicit creation/initialisation of datasource and `sessionFactory`, how can I add `annotatedClasses` to the `hibernateSessionFactory`? Can I do it through `application.properties`?

Here is how the previous context looked like:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="annotatedClasses">
  <list>
    <value>com.example.myEntity</value>
  </list>
</property>
```

We are using following versions:

Spring: 5.1.15.RELEASE,
Spring-Boot: 2.1.14.RELEASE,
Hibernate: 5.4.15.Final

Quick Clarification:

So the whole project is already migrated with proper annotations. The problem comes in just one occurrence where in a Dao we are creating a query. The error is that the entity referenced in that query is not mapped.

Query creation looks as follows:

```
getSession().createQuery("from TemplateImpl t");
```

The error I get is:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TemplateImpl is not mapped.
```

The Dao is annotated with Repository and Transactional and entity (TemplateImpl) is annotated with Entity.

Do I still need to explicitly add annotatedClasses to the sessionFactory? If not then why am I getting this error?

Comment: Use `@ImportResource` to load the xml instead of trying to convert everything. First get a working application using your existing XML files, using `@ImportResource` to load them. Then start to move things to java based configuration and/or use the Spring Boot autoconfiguration. Again baby steps do 1 bean at a time.

Comment: I am already past that point. I have updated the question with new updates. Can you have a look?

Comment: Check to see if your table is correctly mapped to your entity class. https://javabeat.net/hibernate-querysyntaxexception/#:~:text=QuerySyntaxException%20%3A%20Table%20is%20not%20mapped&text=Problem%3A%20This%20problem%20occurs%20only,name%20of%20the%20entity%20class.

Comment: The query is using the exact name of the entity. As it is described in the link you shared.

Comment: If you are following the best practices (that is an `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in a top level package covering all other packages) your entities should be picked up. If that isn't the case you might need to add an `@EntityScan`. Also you shouldn't be using Hibnernate directly (preferably) but rather the `EntityManager` and switch to JPA. With the current state of JPA you rarely need Hibernate and when you do you can simply `unwrap` to the `Session` if you really must. This allows you to take advantage of the JPA auto configuration as well.

Comment: That is exactly how I have done it. I have jpa in my classpath and some jpa relevant properties in application.properties. No other configurations. datasource is also defined through application.properties. But somehow this dao is causing errors. A quick info: This dao is in a commons project with all the other daos and entities. That project is not a spring boot application but a simple spring project. That's why I have component scans in my application context for classes in the commons project.

Answer (score 1):

With the Java based annotation configuration in `Spring Boot`, data access is automatically managed with :

`application.propertie` file:

> here you define, the connection string and all other feature you want
> while accessing your database

`@Repository` interface:

> an interface that helps simplified the boiler plate needed to access a
> database by providing native CRUD functions

`@Entity` class:

> a class that represents your tables in memory

This [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) should help you.

Comment: I forgot to mention somethings in the Original question. So the whole project is already migrated with exactly the annotations that you recommended in your answer. The problem comes in just one occurrence where in a Dao we are creating a query. The error is that the entity referenced in that query is not mapped.

getSession().createQuery("from TemplateImpl t");
The error I get is: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TemplateImpl is not mapped.

The Dao is annotated with Repository and Transactional and entity (TemplateImpl) is annotated with Entity.

Comment: Do I still need to add annotatedClasses explicitly to sessionFactory?
PS: I am updating the question with these details as well.